# iPad Other Storage - what is it and how to clear it up?

Tags: ipad, ios

iTunes reports my iPad has 4Gb of "other" storage (yellow). It was 6Gb before I did a sync.

What is this and what can I do about it?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/whats-in-the-other-category-on-my-ipad/

Answer (score 0):

"Other" data is memory things other than apps, music, or movies use. This usually consists of mainly downloads and other content that your device cannot classify. You can remove it by downloading a file explorer and deleting unwanted items to free up space.